# How to find the coefficient of $x^k$ in the expression $\prod_{p=2}^n (1+xp) $

Tags: co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, integration, stirling-numbers

I got this general formula for $ n\in N$ (I showed it *[here](https://t.me/faoler1/57)*)

$$\int_0^1 \left(\frac{x}{1-x} \ln x \right)^n dx=n \sum_{p=0}^{n-1}a(n,p+1) (-1)^{n-p} \zeta(p+2)+n!  $$
where $a(n,k)$ is the coefficient of $x^{k-1}$ in the expression
$$\prod_{p=2}^n (1+xp)$$

I found in [A145324](https://oeis.org/A145324) this formula using [Stirling numbers of first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind)
$$ a(n,k)=\sum_{p=0}^{k-1} (-1)^p |s_1(n+1,n-p+1)|$$

**MY QUESTION**

how can I prove the last formula that I found in OEIS and is there a closed form for it without using series ?

Comment: Just write $\prod_{p=2}^n (1+xp)=x^{n-1}(1/x+n)_{n-1}$ and then use the definition of Stirling numbers of first kind.

Answer (score 4):

From representation
$$\prod_{p=2}^n (1+xp) = (-x)^{n+1} (-1/x)_{n+1} (1+x)^{-1}=
\sum_{i\geq 0} s_1(n+1,i) (-x)^{n+1-i}\cdot \sum_{j\geq0} (-x)^j,
$$
it follows that the coefficient of $x^{k-1}$ in this product equals
$$(-1)^{k-1} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} s_1(n+1,n+2-k+j).$$

Comment: @CaveJohnson made a related [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1211051) earlier.

Comment: is that result is same ? this make it simplest

Comment: @LSpice: It's not quite what I said in my answer.

Comment: @Faoler: What result do you refer to?

Comment: I mean your formula is different but simple

Comment: @Faoler: It is the same as in your question under the change of variables: $p\mapsto k-1-j$.